# Getting Failure issues in magento commerce cloud when merging code from staging to production

Tags: magento2-cloud, cloud, failure

Hi I am working in  Magento cloud  when merging the code from staging to production i am getting merge conflict issue

**Preparing to merge environment 'staging' into master
Checking out repository
Executing merge
  Auto-merging .magento/routes.yaml
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .magento/routes.yaml
  Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
E: Error: Unable to merge, resolve the conflict manually.**

Please help me if anyone know how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question, But I got the same error today and this is how - I solved it. This may not the appropriate solution.

1. **Take a full Backup of the Branch or Master Branch using**

   *git clone ssh://basantmandal@domain.tld/path/to/my-project.git*
2. **Checkout Branch (Merge from Stage - Production)**

   *git checkout Production*
3. **Merge Using Strategy Option & Allow Unrelated History**

   *git merge origin/staging --strategy-option theirs --allow-unrelated-histories*
4. **Push to Production (Forcefully)**

   *git add . && git push origin production -f*

After this you will see the Production Branch is updated with Staging Branch Updates.